# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.restassured.RestAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am getting the below error. Kindly, help.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.restassured.RestAssured
  at netbanking.pages.APIResponsePages.<init>(APIResponsePages.java:24)
  at netbanking.module.PassbookModule.validateUITransactionsWithAPI(PassbookModule.java:219)
  at testcases.singleuser.PassbookTest.test8validateAPIresponse(PassbookTest.java:157)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
```

I tried to update compile in pom.XML file dependencies with no effect.
Also, uploaded all the jars for restAssured, also with no effect.

Comment: make sure this class in classpath

Comment: yes, it is there in classpath.

Comment: Have you added <scope>test</scope> in pom.xml ? Try removing it

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you update the Java version (usually to a version greater than 8). The solution to this is adding a dependency for groovy as well as rest-assured in your pom.xml file. The below version works for java 17 and below:

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
     <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
     <version>5.3.0</version> 
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
   <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.9</version>
  </dependency>
```

Also make sure to change the .classPath file. You have to change the rest-assured and groovy versions to the versions specified in pom.xml